# How to Hide bottom navigation bar using provider flutter

Tags: flutter, provider, dart-pub, bottom-navigation-bar

I am working on a social media app which contains a home screen with bottom navbar and 5 pages .
Although i am able to change the bool value to show or hide navbar under provider but the changes are not reflecting in widget .

main.dart -

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => 
ScrollProvider(),
        ),
      ],
child : MyApp()
```

My provider class -

```
     class ScrollProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  bool isVisible = true;

  void show() {

      isVisible = true;
      print("in Provider $isVisible");

      notifyListeners();
  }

  void hide() {

      isVisible = false;
      print("in Provider $isVisible");

      notifyListeners();

  }
}
```

Page which has the value scrollcontroller

```
 ScrollController _scrollController =
      ScrollController(); 

      _scrollController.addListener(() {
     
     final direction =
          _scrollController.position.userScrollDirection;

      if (direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
        ScrollProvider().show();
        }
      if (direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {

          ScrollProvider().hide();
      }
    });
```

And my homescreen which which has body and navbar contains this code

‘’’

```
bottomNavigationBar: Consumer<BottomBarVisibilityProvider>(
    builder: (context, bottomBarVisibilityProvider, child) =>
        AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      child: bottomBarVisibilityProvider.isVisible
          ? Wrap(
              children: const [BottomBar()],
            )
          : Wrap(),
    ),
  ),
```

I have initialised the provider inside main.dart

Can someone tell me why its not working .. and what should i do

here is the full code of homepage

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 

  List<Widget> _pages ;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   
    _pages = [
      MemeTabView(scrollController: scrollToHide),
      TempTab(),
      null,
      NotificationScreen(),
      ProfileScreen(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,showAppBar: false),
    ];
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.selectedIndex == null) {
      widget.selectedIndex = 0;
    }

    return
      Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: brandName(),
      ),
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar:
            Consumer<ScrollProvider>(
              builder: (_,scrollProvider,__){
               
                return Container(
                  child: scrollProvider.isVisible == true
                      ?
                      bottomNav()


                      : Container(),
                );
              },
            ),


      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body:PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
       
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: _pages,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Plz provide complete code! Like the whole tree where that bottomNavigationBar is placed etc... As it is now, I'm trying to help you, but I'm doing a lot of guessing... 

Comment: Can you include how you've got `bottomBarVisibilityProvider`, a full minimal widget will be helpful.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, on that I guessed the answer was: `BottomBarVisibilityProvider bottomBarVisibilityProvider = BottomBarVisibilityProvider();` :)

Comment: @GaganKumar, also plz show exactly what you mean by "I have initialised the provider inside main.dart"... Did you pass it as an argument to your MaterialApp for example? Otherwise, that would be the issue...

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i have added the line but still not fixed

Comment: Can you just pass null on `bottomNavigationBar` as I did. Also cant see `_scrollController` on your new snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read provider like

```dart
context.read<BottomBarVisibilityProvider>();
```

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    /// Providers are above [MyApp] instead of inside it, so that tests
    /// can use [MyApp] while mocking the providers
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BottomBarVisibilityProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.\
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const SCCR(),
    );
  }
}

class SCCR extends StatefulWidget {
  const SCCR({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SCCR> createState() => _SCCRState();
}

class _SCCRState extends State<SCCR> {
//just for test purpose
  late final bottomBarVisibilityProvider =
          context.read<BottomBarVisibilityProvider>();
  late final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController()
    ..addListener(() {
     
      final direction = scrollController.position.userScrollDirection;

      if (direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
        if (!bottomBarVisibilityProvider.isVisible) {
          bottomBarVisibilityProvider.show();
        }
      } else if (direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        if (bottomBarVisibilityProvider.isVisible) {
          bottomBarVisibilityProvider.hide();
        }
      }
    });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        child: Container(
          height: 3333,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Consumer<BottomBarVisibilityProvider>(
        builder: (context, bottomBarVisibilityProvider, child) =>
            AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          child: bottomBarVisibilityProvider.isVisible
              ? Wrap(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: 100,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : null,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I will suggest to follow [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/)

Comment: thank you so much bro it worked like a charm . I have forgot to add context.read<BottomBarVisibilityProvider>(); this line where in the file which contains scrollcontroller

Comment: Glad to help, also check the doc more.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use my providers:

I have 3 different providers here, `MyThemeClass`, `NewMsgListener` and `FirebaseProvider`. All of them extend `ChangeNotifierProvider`. And this is my main:

```
import 'package:my_app/my_firebase.dart';
import 'package:my_app/global.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:navigation_history_observer/navigation_history_observer.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:my_app/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:my_app/screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:my_app/new_msg_listener.dart';
import 'package:my_app/provider_updates.dart';
import 'package:my_app/theme.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MyFirebase.myFutureFirebaseApp =
      Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  final NewMsgListener newMsgListener = NewMsgListener();
  final MyThemeClass myThemeClass = MyThemeClass();
  await myThemeClass.getMyTheme();
  print('getMyTheme() is ready');

  await MyFirebase.myFutureFirebaseApp;

  runApp(MyApp(myThemeClass, newMsgListener));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp(this.myThemeClass, this.newMsgListener, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
  final MyThemeClass myThemeClass;
  final NewMsgListener newMsgListener;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building $runtimeType');
    FirebaseProvider firebaseProvider = FirebaseProvider();

    firebaseProvider.initialize(GlobalVariable.navState);

    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<FirebaseProvider>(
              create: (context) => firebaseProvider),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => myThemeClass),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => newMsgListener),
        ],
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: Provider.of<MyThemeClass>(context).currentTheme,
            home: WelcomeScreen(myThemeClass),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            navigatorObservers: [NavigationHistoryObserver()],
            navigatorKey: GlobalVariable.navState,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Not that it's important, but my `my_firebase.dart` file looks like this (just so you don't need to wonder!):

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:my_app/firebase_labels.dart';

class MyFirebase {
  static Future<FirebaseApp>? myFutureFirebaseApp;  //Initialized from main()
  static FirebaseFirestore storeObject = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  static auth.FirebaseAuth authObject = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
}
```

Does that provider management work for you?